# Jquery event on click

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having trouble to solve my problem of clicking 5 buttons using Jquery.
I want all 5 buttons clicked, but not at the same time. Instead, I want to execute a button called "Update All". After executing, I want that all 5 buttons get clicked 1 by 1, with 3 seconds gap, then stop at the 5th button.
Here is my code, but this code clicks all buttons, with no interval. So this won't work if the internet is really slow.

Thanks in advance for the Help.
By the way, this code was inside the while loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#updateAll').click(function(){        
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#SubmitFormData<?php echo $chili_id; ?>").trigger('click');
    }, 3000);        
  });
});
```

Comment: Please include the code for the buttons you're talking about.

Comment: The button has the only the ID this #SubmitFormData<?php echo $chili_id; ?> it is a submit button that has ID i have 5 forms that i need to submit all at the same time but with 3 seconds delay on each

Comment: Ok, I asked nicely. :-)

Comment: Ahahaha no problem thanks for asking @KIKOSoftware Thanks

Comment: Please use English, instead of SMS-English. Punctuation and a few capital letters are such a nice tradition.

Comment: Yunnosch sorry i am not good in English by the way if my question is not valid because of my bad English its Ok. I will try to resolve or find another way.. thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('#updateAll').on('click',function(){
     var inputBtn=$('.saveBtn');
     var C=0; 
     var setInter=setInterval(function(){
        if( C==inputBtn.leangh) 
           clearInterval(setInter);  
           $(inputBtn[C]).click(); 
           C++; 
     }, 3000); 
 });
     
    $('.saveBtn').on("click",function(){
     console.log($(this).val());
    });       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="updateAll" value="updateAll"/>
<br>
<input type="button" class="saveBtn" value="click 1"/>
<input type="button" class="saveBtn" value="click 2"/>
<input type="button" class="saveBtn" value="click 3"/>
<input type="button" class="saveBtn" value="click 4"/>
<input type="button" class="saveBtn" value="click 5"/>
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much @Farhad it works 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#updateAll').click(function(){        
  var inputBtn=$('.saveBtn');
  var C=0;
  var setInter=setInterval(function(){ 

  if( C==inputBtn.leangh)
       clearInterval(setInter);    
     $(inputBtn[C]).click();
      C++;
  }, 3000);
 });
});

Comment: Yes thank you so much @Farhad it works flawlessly. I want to vote for your answer but i don't know how?.

Comment: Maybe i am not yet eligible to vote, I cant find anywhere on the page that tick box for voting.. Sorry man but i am really glad that you helped me for the 2 days problem.

Comment: This image shows its location. By doing so, you get the same score https://ibb.co/nDMrRk

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i=1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#update").click(function(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
     if(i<=5)
     {
       $("#"+i).click();
       alert("button"+i+"click");
     }
     i++;
    },3000);  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="update" class="btn" value="Update All"/>
<br/><br/><br/>
<input type="button" id="1" class="btn" value="click 1"/>
<input type="button" id="2" class="btn" value="click 2"/>
<input type="button" id="3" class="btn" value="click 3"/>
<input type="button" id="4" class="btn" value="click 4"/>
<input type="button" id="5" class="btn" value="click 5"/>
```